# dropdown functionality not working in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have an issue when attempting to click on an element from a drop-down menu, when running a test in Selenium. So, as per the below screenshot, I am hovering over 'Reports', then 'Asset Management', then 'Terminated Report: Pending'. Clicking on the 'Terminated Report: Pending' option should take me to the appropriate page
[image: Screenshot 1]

I've written the following code in WebDriver to do this:

```
    public static void terminatedReportPendingFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    WebElement terminatedReportPendingFocus = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'GetTerminatedPendingReport')]"));
    terminatedReportPendingFocus.click();
}
```

I didn't see any issues with this, given that I had used similar code in order to access the 'Terminated Report: Pending' page. However, for some reason when I run the test, whilst the browser initially focuses on the element I want, it then loses focus and drops down to the 'Collections' drop down and selects a page with a completely different href to the one I selected in the code. Can anyone help as to what the reason might be? Many thanks

**ASSET MANAGEMENT IMPLEMENTATION**

```
    public static void assetManagementFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    WebElement assetManagementFocus = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()='Asset Management']"));
    Actions hoverOnReportWindow = new Actions(driver);
    hoverOnReportWindow.moveToElement(assetManagementFocus).build().perform();
    assetManagementFocus.click();
}
```

**COMPLETE IMPLEMENTATION OF CODE**

```
public class optionFocusControls {

//REPORTS TAB   
public static void reportWindowFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    WebElement reportWindowFocus = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Reports"));
    Actions hoverOnReportText = new Actions(driver);
    hoverOnReportText.moveToElement(reportWindowFocus).build().perform();           
}

public static void assetManagementFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    WebElement assetManagementFocus = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()='Asset Management']"));
    Actions hoverOnReportWindow = new Actions(driver);
    hoverOnReportWindow.moveToElement(assetManagementFocus).build().perform();
    assetManagementFocus.click();
}

public static void daysInStockFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    WebElement daysInStockFocus = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()='ET Days In Stock']"));
    Actions hoverOnDaysInStock = new Actions(driver);
    hoverOnDaysInStock.moveToElement(daysInStockFocus).build().perform();
    daysInStockFocus.click();
}

public static void terminatedReportCompletedFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    WebElement terminatedReportCompletedFocus = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'GetTerminatedCompletedReport')]"));    
    terminatedReportCompletedFocus.click();
}

public static void terminatedReportPendingFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    WebElement terminatedReportPendingFocus = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'GetTerminatedPendingReport')]"));
    terminatedReportPendingFocus.click();
}
```

}

**FIX - 01/12/14**

```
    public static void terminatedReportPendingFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Terminated Report: Completed')]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);      
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of your implementation for the same? I am interested to known the element detection method for 'Asset Management'.

Comment: Hi Rupesh, thanks for replying. I've attached the implementation code above, entitled 'ASSET MANAGEMENT IMPLEMENTATION'

Comment: I have modified my code and included manual wait for 3 sec. please test and let me know

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. so I just need to add this manual wait for 3 seconds to the snippet of code I placed on my original note? THe Asset Management functionality was working ok, so do I not need to apply the wait command to that section of code?

Comment: Thats Wonderful..Would love if you make my answer as correct  or Upvote it so that other users with the same problem may fix in the same way.

Comment: Hi, sorry Rupesh, sorry what I was asking was do i apply the 'wait' command to just the 'TerminatedReportPending' code? Or, do I need to apply it to the Asset Management Implementation, too, as this did work previously?

Comment: Try using manual wait for both the actions.

Comment: Hi Rupesh, I have applied manual waits as advised, but unfortunately the issue still occurs. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me the complete implementation of your code?

Comment: Hi Rupesh, I've attached this above (entitled 'COMPLETE IMPLEMENTATION OF CODE'). Just to note, everything works correctly until the 'terminatedReportPendingFocus' method

Comment: Is the site publicly available?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's an intranet website used by a company I work for

Comment: I'm just thinking if there is some more suitable xpath I could use, to see if this could fix the issue.....but I can't think of any

Comment: Alright..About the only last method which is not working i.e terminatedReportPendingFocus . 1)  Can you tell me where the cursor is before this method starts executing?  2) When Terminated report Completed method is executed then does the Asset Mgmnt and Its Sub-menu gets hide again?

Comment: Lets give a  try with driver.findElement(By.xpath("//class[contains(text(),'Terminated Report: Pending')]"));

Comment: Hi Rupesh, apologies for the delay. I've tried the above code but I get an error advising "Unable to find element with xpath". I tried a Thread.sleep but this didn't work

Comment: Sorry Andy, My Apology for the wrong Xpath.   please try (By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Terminated Report: Pending')]"));

Comment: Hi Rupesh, unfortunately it is still losing the focus and going to another option from the drop-down list....very bizarre.

Comment: I'm wondering whether the issue is with the text being stipulated in the xpath, and whether I can find by e.g. div[1]/id[2] etc...

Comment: Try this one ....     WebElement terminatedReportPendingFocus = (new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Terminated Report: Pending')]")));
     terminatedReportPendingFocus.click();

Comment: Thanks Rupesh....still does the same thing I'm afraid. What I have noticed (if you look at the screenshot at the top) is that the 'ET Days In Stock' and 'Terminated Report: Completed' drop-downs work. But from 'Terminated Report: Pending' onwards they all behave in the same way in that they lose focus and go to the 'Collections: Breached Report' page

Comment: Managed to fix the issue, Rupesh! I've put the code in above entitled 'Fix - 1/12/14'. Is 'sendKeys' OK to use in this scenario, are there any pitfalls you can see?

Comment: Ha Got it. It was just moving to it and not clicking on it. Finally Its up . Great.  .....Cheers

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your help with this Rupesh, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code and let me know what happens

```
WebElement Reports = driver.findElement(By.xpath("--------//---As per your code"));
WebElement Asset Management = driver.findElement(By.xpath("--------//---As per your code"));
WebElement Terminated_Report_Pending = driver.findElement(By.xpath("--------//---As per your code"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(Reports).perform();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        builder.moveToElement(Asset Management).perform();
        Terminated_Report_Pending.click();
```

---

Try below from in your code

```
public static void assetManagementFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    WebElement assetManagementFocus = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()='Asset Management']"));
    Actions hoverOnReportWindow = new Actions(driver);
    hoverOnReportWindow.moveToElement(assetManagementFocus).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    assetManagementFocus.click();
}
```